# get the undeliverable email address with mimekit/mailkit library

Tags: c#, mailkit

I started using @jstedfast [Mimekit/Mailkit library](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit), which is great by the way,  to pull undeliverables using its subject line for search. I tried using the message.to, message.resentto.

how do i get that information. My first try today. I was able to get the list and the body but I just need the email. I tried using s22.imap but there's no support anymore then I discovered this. I know you're active here @jstedfast I need you help..there's no discussion tab in your github.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do? Did a message you tried to send fail and now you are trying to get which email address caused the SMTP server to fail? Or?

Comment: @jstedfast Here's the scenario. I'll send mass email then when there's undeliverable the application is supposed to check which emails is undeliverables. I was able to pull these emails using subject search. how do i get the email address of these emails? thank you sir

Comment: looks like the only way to get that is search within the body. is there a shortcut with your library.? like search by subject?? just wondering..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the raw message source, does the value of the `Content-Type` header match something along the lines of `multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status`? If so, it is very likely that this message will have a sub-part with a `Content-Type` header with a value of `message/delivery-status`. It *should* be the second child part of the `multipart/report` (the first part should be a human-readable explanation).

If so, you can cast the `message/delivery-status` `MimeEntity` to an instance of a `MessageDeliveryStatus`. You'll notice that the `MessageDeliveryStatus` class has a property called `StatusGroups` which is a list of multiple collections of headers (e.g. a list of `HeaderList` objects).

Each `HeaderList` contains information about a particular recipient that failed. I think what you want to do is look at the `Final-Recipient` header which will contain 2 pieces of information:

1. The address-type (should typically be `"rfc822"`)
2. The mailbox of the recipient (which is what you want)

Unfortunately, MimeKit does not have any tools to parse the `Final-Recipient` header, but it should be trivial to locate the end of the `address-type` parameter in the header value by using `IndexOf (';')` and then you can use something like `MailboxAddress.TryParse()` to parse it (or you could probably just `Substring()` the value w/o parsing).

So, the way this might look in code is this:

```
string[] GetUndeliverableAddresses (MimeMessage message)
{
    var report = message.Body as MultipartReport;

    if (report == null)
        throw new ArgumentException ("This is not a multipart/report!");

    MessageDeliveryStatus status = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < report.Count; i++) {
        status = report[i] as MessageDeliveryStatus;
        if (status != null)
            break;
    }

    if (status == null)
        throw new ArgumentException ("Did not contain a message/delivery-status!");

    var undeliverables = new List<string> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < status.StatusGroups.Count; i++) {
        var recipient = status.StatusGroups[i]["Final-Recipient"];
        int semicolon = recipient.IndexOf (';');

        var undeliverable = recipient.Substring (semicolon + 1).Trim ();
        undeliverables.Add (undeliverable);
    }

    return undeliverables.ToArray ();
}
```

For more information on `message/delivery-status`, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you sir.. I ended up..using bodypart and select the 2nd element. since it has that "final recipient" tag.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did

```
 foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query))
        {
            var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
           // Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
            //Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Headers);
           // Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.BodyParts);
            var text = message.BodyParts;
            string src = text.ElementAt(1).ToString();
            int srcStart = src.IndexOf("RFC822;",0); << i used final-recipient intially
            int srcEnd   = src.IndexOf("Action", 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Email:" + src.Substring(srcStart + 8, srcEnd - (srcStart + 8)));
            Console.WriteLine(src);


            //foreach (var part in message.BodyParts)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(part);
            //    // do something
            //}

        }
```

let me know if there could be a problem..will I get the rfc822 if the recipient inbox is full? there's no way i can test that.. I tested with emails with nonexistent domain, mailbox does not exist..with live.com, randomdomain.com,yahoo.com and gmail. gmail, on the other hand does not return any undeliverables.

Comment: I would recommend using something closer to my code above instead because it'll be less error-prone. The text "RFC822;" might appear in other places of the message in some cases. Not all SMTP servers will send you a notification when delivery fails. GMail, for example, does not because it is their intention to subvert spammers trying to exploit this system to discover email addresses through brute force.

Comment: thanks for the info. i'll prolly double filter using final-recipeint then the rfc822. im using office365.com

Comment: Why not use MimeKit's MessageDeliveryStatus class? That's what it's there for. Calling `ToString()` on a `MimeEntity` is expensive and unnecessary.

Comment: i just started using your library yesterday..i didn't explore it yet. thanks for the info. I'll consider it.